# Zend_Cache::throwException('Invalid backend...') magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.8

I am trying to install mangeto CE1.8 on a dedicated server but I am getting error.

I tried these solutions http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/77573/

but there is no cache folder I found. I create a new cache folder but no success.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:23:"Invalid backend name []";i:1;s:1413:"#0 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/lib/Zend/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::throwException('Invalid backend...')
#1 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/TwoLevels.php(135): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('', Array, true, true)
#2 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('TwoLevels', Array, true, true)
#4 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'TwoLevels', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#5 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#6 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#7 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#8 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#9 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#10 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

any solution for fix this.

Comment: there is no cache folder.

Comment: Which cache you are using ?

Comment: this is the fresh magneto 1.8 installation. so there is no cache extension and I didn't found any cache folder with in /app/code/core/Zend/

Comment: Open \lib\Zend\Cache.php on line 136 try to echo $backend and $standardBackends

Comment: Check in local.xml file for the tags <cache>
  <backend>...</backend> if its properly set

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy : $backend is null and $standardBackends is standardBackends

Comment: error fix by deleting local.xml
thanks to every one.

Comment: Backend must be File while standard backends could be  `Sqlite
Memcached
Libmemcached
Apc
ZendPlatform
Xcache
TwoLevels
ZendServer_Disk
ZendServer_ShMem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please delete old local.xml and try again.
it will help you.:)

Comment: there is two files in magento local.xml. can u elaborate the correct file.